# Appropriate way to subclass Guava's ImmutableSet

Tags: java, guava

I have a class along the lines of

```
class Receipt
{
     private Set<Order> orders;
     public Receipt(Set<Order> orders)
     {
         this.orders = ImmutableSet.copyOf(orders)
     }   
}
```

This has served me well.

However, because of some type-erasure & persistence issues I'm facing, I'd like to now introduce a form of

```
class OrderSet extends Set<Order> {}
```

Obviously I can't extend `Set<Order>`, as it's an interface.  I'd like to keep my implementation as immutable.  However, I can't extend `ImmutableSet<Order>`, as the docs state:

> Note: Although this class is not final, it cannot be subclassed
>   outside its package as it has no public or protected constructors.
>   Thus, instances of this type are guaranteed to be immutable.

I could use composition, giving `OrderSet` a backing collection of `ImmutableSet` and delegate all the `Set` methods to it.  However, this seems overkill.

Is there another way I can achieve a non-generic subclass here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, composition isn't overkill, it's exactly the way to go.

You should create your `OrderSet` as follows because, as Louis emphasizes in the comments, *this use case* is exactly what they're meant for:

```
public class OrderSet extends ForwardingSet<Order> {
  private final ImmutableSet<Order> orders;
  public class OrderSet (Set<Order> orders) {
    this.orders = ImmutableSet.copyOf(orders);
  }
  protected ImmutableSet<Order> delegate() { return orders; }
}
```

The immutable classes in Guava are designed so that you don't extend them. You *have to use composition* and it's precisely the right way to go.

Comment: Also, remember to make your IDE type the delegation methods for you. In eclipse, Source-Generate Delegated Method

Comment: This is _exactly_ what `ForwardingSet` and its friends are for.

Comment: Also, @PabloGrisafi, your comment is wrong.  You should just override `ForwardingSet.delegate()`, and don't override any methods whose behavior isn't being changed.